# How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

Instead of the default icons or the text option, I would like to have numbered entries in my bibliography.

I added the line:

`\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}`

to get rid of the icons, but can't figure out how to get numbers to display in their place. The references in the content slides are numbered, but without the corresponding number in the bibliography it's not very helpful.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hspace*{0.1cm}
    \text{short title}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \insertshortauthor
    \hspace{3.5cm}
    \insertsectionhead
    \hfill
    \insertframenumber
    /
    \inserttotalframenumber
    \hspace{0.1cm}
}

\title{a title}
\author[me]{my full name}
\institute{where I work}
\date{today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{1st slide}
    Some text. \cite{ref_1} More interesting text. \cite{ref_2} Some even more interesting stuff. \cite{ref_3} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
    \tiny{\bibliographystyle{abbrv} }
    \bibliography{refs}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@inproceedings{ref_1,
  title={title 1},
  author={A. Author},
  booktitle={book title},
  year={2010}
}
@article{ref_2,
  title={title 2},
  author={B. Author},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={35},
  number={10},
  pages={1217--1256},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
@incollection{ref_3,
  title={title 3},
  author={C. Author},
  booktitle={book title},
  pages={595--606},
  year={2012},
  publisher={publisher}
}
```

Resulting bibliography:

[image: The bibliography I get using the supplied code. No numbers next to the entry.]

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### Edited answer

<sup>This works independently of the bibliography style, and with `biblatex` as well.</sup>

According to the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), subsection 10.6, you can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
```

instead of

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
```

so that the bib label is inserted for each bib item.

The result is:

[image]

### Original answer

<sup>This works in the particular case of the OP, because using the bibliography style `abbrv`, `\insertbiblabel` inserts `[\theenumiv]`.</sup>

I think the `beamer` class uses the counter `enumiv` to number the items in the `thebibliography` environment as the standard classes.

So, substituting the line

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
```

with

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
```

you should obtain what you want:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! But out of curiosity, is this listed somewhere in the documentation? I looked, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you mean in the `beamer` documentation, the answer is no. I've used a trick with the `enumiv` counter.

Comment: In fact, you can simply use `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}`.

Comment: When using biblatex+biber, karlkoellers answer results in all items labelled [0], but @GonzaloMedina's answer works correctly.

Comment: For me (biblatex+biber) neither method works. This seems to come from the fact that my style is authoryear. I then use \footcite and I like the way this looks. It seems though that you need to use numerics style in order for this to work. Is there a solution using the authoryear style. Would it be possible to insert the footcite number in the same way you insert the biblabel?

Comment: @karlkoeller Hi sir, I am getting the number bullets but the order is not in sync, How to get the first citation as the first reference and so on?

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer didn't work with `biblatex` as all reference numbers became zero. What worked was to substitute the line:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
```

in the code example with:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
```

and that works with both `bibtex` and `biblatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. People usually give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) - please do so too.

Comment: This answer does not work in the code set-up of the question.

Comment: It does work in the code set-up of the question, I just double-checked it. The answer I posted works with both bibtex and biblatex, but the accepted answer only works with bibtex. Since this method took a while to find I thought I'd post it in case anyone else wanted to use biblatex to do the same.