# citation in beamer as ieee style

Tags: beamer, citing

I would like to cite numerous references in beamer. Everything is Ok except the way beamer orders the references. It shows the references by the first names not by numbers which makes it harder to refer to the actual reference. References look like the following picture [image: here]

however in the presentation, they are numbered such as [2], [4]. With many references, it is difficult to count a certain reference. My question is Is there a way to show the number beside each reference?

```
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I found out the answer here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124256/how-do-i-get-numbered-entries-in-a-beamer-bibliography

Comment: Since you already found the answer, I closed this question as a duplicate.