# Change Bibliography Icon/Label with Beamer Class

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm doing a presentation in latex. I have included the references using bibtex, however, the references appear as images and not numbers:

Main code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

\title{My Presentation} 
\author{Thunder} 
\today

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle} 

\begin{frame}{Contents}
    \vspace{-1.20cm}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\include{Objective}
\include{References}

\end{document}
```

References:

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\vspace{-0.50cm}
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

Output:

[image]

Does anyone knows why the reference is not appearing as a number?

My bib entry is:

```
@misc{Guide,
 author               = {Guide},
 howpublished         = {Guide},
 title                = {The Guide},
 year                 = {2014},
}
```

Comment: what does your `.bib` entry look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to place

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
```

before `\bibliographystyle`.

The purpose of these icons, quoted from the [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

> Unlike normal LaTeX, the default template for the bibliography does
>   not repeat the citation text (like “[Dijkstra, 1982]”) before each
>   item in the bibliography. Instead, a cute, small article symbol is
>   drawn. The rationale is that the audience will not be able to remember
>   any abbreviated citation texts till the end of the talk.

There's a nice [overview of the different icons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon) at another question.

Comment: It should be `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{text}` instead of `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]`. With **curly brackets**.
See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124271/110154) answer

Comment: @Ben `[text]` is a predefined option (see the "overview of different icons" link I referenced). The Beamer template command is defined as: `\setbeamertemplate{⟨element name⟩}[⟨predefined option⟩]⟨args⟩` (see [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section "16.3.3 Setting Beamer’s Templates"). With squared brackets, you'll use a predefined option, with *curly* brackets, i.e. the `args`, you set the text for the element.