# Instead of numbers, symbols are showing up in the references using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using biblatex for creating a poster.I made a small example with all the packages I am using.

```
    \documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,maxcitenames=3,backend=bibtex,url=false,doi=false,isbn=false,hyperref=false,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[lf]{venturis}
\usepackage[version-1-compatibility]{siunitx}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}
\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] 

\begin{document}

tedhjfshsofhewihewi\cite{Meyer1996a}nfoeeghraeoghru

\begin{minipage}{0.98\columnwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
         \noindent
             %\scriptsize

                        %\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
                %\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
                %\bibliography{library}
                \printbibliography
                %\vspace{3em}
        \end{multicols} 
            \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

In principle everything is fine. No error messages and no bibtex related warnings. I get the (1) in the text. 
However in the reference list, instead of

> (1) **Author1**, Title1, *Journal1*...

I get

> [image] **Author1**, Title1,
>   *Journal1*

Any ideas? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: For a better overview I put this in a comment: this error is independent from the style I use; the normal standard bibtex does not produce the same error (However the standard bibtex is not offering the reference-style I need)

Comment: This is a `beamer` thing so the beamer doc will help, but i can't  remember the name. I'll start searching.

Comment: Here we go: [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124256)