# Bibliography in ieee format in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I can create bibliography at the end of my beamer presentation manually in IEEE style using

```
\begin{the bibliography}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}
```

When I do this, I do not get

```
[1] Author, Paper, etc...
```

but I get as shown in the attached image. I want square brackets with numbers.[image] How to do it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber at the end

Comment: @Johannes_B I have modified the question. Please check

Comment: Does this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124271/27635