# Print a list of references in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I want to be able to print certain references (separately) on the same frame using biblatex. I thought I could do that using `\newrefcontext`, however this didn't work as the MWE below shows. All reference are printed whenever `\printbibliography` is executed.

Additionally, is there a way to have the references number on the frame instead of showing the small page icon? Using `\defbibenvironment`, which works in normal documents, doesn't seem to work in beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2012a,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part I},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    language = {English},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    month   = {1},
    year    = {2012},
}
@article{Doe2019a,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part II},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {2},
    pages   = {1--30},
    month   = {1},
    year    = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true, hyperref]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
{\scriptsize\begin{enumerate}}%
  {\end{enumerate}}%
{\item}%


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  First reference only: \newrefcontext \nocite{Doe2012} \printbibliography

  \vskip 1cm%
  All references: \newrefcontext \nocite{*} \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep bibliographies separate you use `refsection`s not `refcontext`s. `refcontext`s control sorting and similar context-dependent data. `refsection`s keep bibliographies and citations completely separate. There are also `refsegment`s, which can be used to subdivide bibliographies without keeping them independent.

Your example works as intended if you use

```
\newrefsection
```

instead of `\newrefcontext`.

You can get the bibliography numbering back with `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` as explained in [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124256/35864).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\scriptsize\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}%

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2012a,
  author   = {J. Doe},
  title    = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part I},
  journal  = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
  language = {English},
  volume   = {1},
  pages    = {1--10},
  month    = {1},
  year     = {2012},
}
@article{Doe2019a,
  author  = {J. Doe},
  title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part II},
  journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
  volume  = {2},
  pages   = {1--30},
  month   = {1},
  year    = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  First reference only: \newrefsection \nocite{Doe2012a} \printbibliography

  \vskip 1cm
  All references: \newrefsection \nocite{*} \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliographies]