# Display citation key in bibliography in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have a beamer presentation where I cite books and papers using alphanumeric keys (as provided by the `style = alphabetic` flag). The whole thing looks as follows:

[image: current citation]

In the bibliography on the last page however I do not have the alphanumeric keys:

[image: current bibliography]

I wonder whether I could also have the alphanumeric keys be displayed in the bibliography instead of just the reference and the icon.

My biblatex configuration currently looks as follows:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
```

I have tried a lot of things and failed but I assume there is probably an easy way to fix this.

Comment: I found something similar [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124256/how-do-i-get-numbered-entries-in-a-beamer-bibliography). I hope this might help you!

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much!