# beamer + biblatex: authoryear causes problem with "\insertbiblabel"

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber

**Introduction**

- I want to use `biblatex` (`biber`) in `beamer`.
- I also want to use the style `authoryear`.
- In order to have the cite label (e. g. `<Author YYYY>`) instead of a symbol in the bibliography, I use `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124256) for example.
- Sadly, this causes the error `! Undefined control sequence.\beamer@@tmpl@bibliography item ->\insertbiblabel`.

**Questions**

1. Can you reproduce the problem?
2. Do you have a solution?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[
    style = authoryear % (un)comment for testing
    ]{biblatex}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} % (un)comment for testing

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\cite{doody}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My system is a up-to-date TeXLive 2020: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.3.2) 2 MAR 2021 23:22`

Comment: I think `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` only works if the bibliography list is naturally labelled, for `biblatex` this is the case with the `numeric` and `alphabetic` styles, but not with `authoryear`. (Compare `style=numeric,`, `style=alphabetic,` and `style=authoryear,` with `\documentclass{article}` to see what it means to be 'naturally labelled'.) For `authoryear` you can avoid icons with `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}`. Note that the result is enough to identify the citation uniquely. Repeating the citation label in the bibliography would be redundant.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the comment. In my use case it still would be beneficial but if it's is not "out of the box" possible then I have to accept it :).

Comment: I don't think it is easily possible out of the box, but it is certainly not impossible. But I think labelled lists with author-year labels have the problem that they waste a lot of space. If you cite my favourite, `sigfridsson`, about one third of the width of your bibliography slide will be occupied by "Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998". That doesn't make for best space efficiency.

Comment: Just to show how this could look like I cooked up https://gist.github.com/moewew/98bcbfb317159a869b31caf41a2f165c (this is just a quick thing I put together, because I have to leave soon, it is not for production use). I absolute **do not recommend** you use this, because I find it wrong to abuse `alphabetic` to get an author-year style and because the output is as it is.

Comment: @moewe Ok, understood. I am also offline soon (midnight for me). If you do not recommend it then I will not go for it.

Comment: @moewe BTW, crazy how fast you put together the proof of concept!

Comment: I might write something up later in case no one else has. There must be ways to get something slightly more sensible without abusing the `alphabetic` style, which I would find less problematic, but the main conceptual issue of redundancy and waste of space will probably still apply. Anyway, good night!

Comment: Have you tried `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\printfield{labelnumber}]}` instead?

Comment: @Timm Can't test it the next days, I am on vacation. But thanks for the the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
```

and

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
```

are equivalent (assuming standard definitions), so this answer applies to both of these definitions equally.

---

With `biblatex`, `\insertbiblabel` only works with styles that have a labelled bibliography list (`numeric` and `alphabetic` styles; to see what it means to have a 'labelled' bibliography list compare the output of `style=alphabetic,` and `style=authoryear,` with `\documentclass{article}`). The `authoryear` style does not have a labelled bibliography list and it does not repeat the citation labels in the bibliography.

So with `authoryear` there simply is no label for `\insertbiblabel` to insert.

I would just use

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \cite{doody,sigfridsson}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”]

which gives you fundamentally the same output as with `\documentclass{article}`.

---

If you want to repeat the citation labels in the bibliography to make it easier to find entries, you can use `biblatex-ext` as follows

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyt,
  introcite=label,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

% avoid error about \insertbiblabel being undefined
\preto{\bibsetup}{\providecommand*{\insertbiblabel}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \cite{doody,sigfridsson}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thanks! I "preto" common command? Do you consider this a hack or is this long-term stable and is unlikely to beak anytime soon, e. g. when Beamer or biblatex get updates?

Comment: I am offline now and will reply tomorrow if applicable. Again, thanks.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `\preto` is one of the `etoolbox` patching commands. I don't know if "common command" is a useful classification here. I would say it is ... established, but I wouldn't want to guess how much it is used in the real world. I'd say this is fairly stable: Even though we have to work around the standard settings of `beamer` here (whose implementation has changed a bit in the past) we do so in a way that should be safe even in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up!