# How do I display serial number in reference section in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usetheme{Goettingen}
   \usecolortheme{whale}
   \usepackage{verbatim}
```

And this is the bibliography

```
    \begin{frame}{\LARGE References}
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{S1}
        \small{Source 1}
        
        \bibitem{S2}
        \small{Source 2}
        
        \bibitem{S3}
        \small{Source 3}
        
        \bibitem{S4}
        \small{Source 4}
        \bibitem{S5}
        \small{Source 5}
        \bibitem{S6}
    \small{Source 6}    
        
    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}
```

In the slide it displays like this
[image]

However I couldn't figure out how to display numbers instead of this paper symbol. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Adding `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` should help.

Comment: See also: [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124256/134144)